# Webform submitted data field names

Tags: webforms

I am beginning a module which implements the hook_webform_submission_insert. I am successfully getting the following data from my implementation of that hook:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [nid] => 3401
    [uid] => 1
    [submitted] => 1425491295
    [remote_addr] => http://myserver.com
    [is_draft] => 0
    [data] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Chandler Mann
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => tecutij@yahoo.com
                        )

                )
.
.
.
```

I need to write code to programmatically map each value index to node fields in a process of creating nodes from custom code.

**However, as the output above does not have field names, it's difficult to map correctly to the necessary node fields.**

Can anyone advice how I might discover what name webform assigns to the field#id 2, 3 etc as in my code sample above?

Answer (score 2):

The `$node` argument to `hook_webform_submission_insert()` contains the info you're looking for. For a Webform node, you'll find an array `$node->webform->components` where, for example, `$node->webform->components[2]` would correspond to the item whose value is "Chandler Mann" in your data.

Answer (score 2):

The `$submission->data` array is keyed by Webform internal component IDs, which you can't see from the admin interface.

You can build a helper array mapping form keys to component IDs:

```
$compMap = array();
foreach ($node->webform['components'] as $c) {
  $compMap[$c['form_key']] = $c['cid'];
}
```

Then you can get the values by form keys as follows:

```
if (array_key_exists($compMap[$key], $submission->data)) {
  $value = $submission->data[$compMap[$key]]['value'][0];
}
else {
  // No value was entered for this field.
}
```

Note, that the value will be in the `['value'][0]` element only for "simple" fields, like text or number. For other types, e.g. reference fields, check your data.